# AWS SAM - Circular dependency between resources error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I followed this [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/amazon-aws/tutorial-use-aws-lambda-s3-real-time-data-processing/) to setup an AWS Lambda function that is invoked upon an upload to S3 and populates DynamoDB.

I'm trying to achieve the same with [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) for which I need to define a `template.yaml` file with the configuration information. I keep getting this error when deploying with Cloudformation -

```
Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Circular dependency between resources: [LambdaPerm]
```

I could not find a lot of information on this so I'm struggling to debug. What's causing this error and how can I resolve this? Here's my template configuration -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  Gradebook:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: LambdaGradebookServerless
      Handler: serverless.LambdaGradebook
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: ./target/serverless-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      Role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/lambda-s3-execution-role
  LambdaPerm:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Ref: Gradebook
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount:
        Ref: AWS::xxxxxxxxxxxx
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Join:
        - ':'
        - - arn
          - aws
          - s3
          - ''
          - ''
          - Ref: gradebookBucket
  gradebookBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      Bucket: gradebook-lambda
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Function:
            Ref: Gradebook
```

Comment: BTW: You can use !Ref "AWS::AccountId" rather than hard-coding your account ID.  Not the cause of your circular dependency though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this circular dependency, create the S3 bucket and the Lambda function independently, then update the stack with an [S3 notification configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes searching for this, I wrote a blog to address this scenario.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/resolving-circular-dependency-in-provisioning-of-amazon-s3-buckets-with-aws-lambda-event-notifications/

The implementation approach is similar to what jarmod describes in the accepted answer. The event notification is setup later using a CloudFormation custom resource.

Answer (score 0):

I got the circular dependency error and it turns out it was a missing parameter that I was referencing from the resource on the CloudFormation template!.