# Unable to put notification event to trigger CloudFormation Lambda in existing S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I'm migrating a "hand built" AWS infrastructure stack to CloudFormation using a [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html) template. I've successfully migrated almost all of the resources, but I've hit a roadblock regarding migrating an S3 bucket. Where I'm running into an issue is with a Lambda function that handles S3 bucket events such as `object create` and `object delete`.

I researched and tried several options, including attaching the Lambda trigger event to a pre-existing S3 bucket on stack creation, but [I learned that this was not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022208/2373676) because the S3 bucket is not part of the CloudFormation stack being built.

Next I tried to create a new bucket in the CloudFormation stack and attach the event object. At first I tried to use existing SAM template shortcuts to create the event between the S3 buckets and the Lambda, but doing so produced a `Circular dependency between resources` error that turned out to be due to [circular permissions required between the bucket and the lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979934/aws-sam-circular-dependency-between-resources-error).

To work around the circular dependency issue I created an auxiliary custom resource Lambda that runs during the CloudFormation stack creation process that uses the S3 API to PUT the notification directly. I attempted to follow the example solution provided in the [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022208/2373676), wherein one PUTS an event into the S3 bucket using a custom resource. Using this apporach my CloudFormation build always fails with the same error message: `Unable to validate the following destination configurations`. To solve this issue I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47674337/2373676) on StackOverflow and added `AWS::Lambda::Permission` and `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy` resources to my CloudFormation template. Despite my changes the error still occurs.

What am I missing?

Here is a snippet of my template.yaml:

```yaml
  IngestClip:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      CodeUri: functions/ingestClip/
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  IngestClipPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref ConfigureLambdaS3Event
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      SourceArn: !GetAtt IngestBucket.Arn

  IngestBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  IngestBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref IngestBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - 's3:PutBucketNotification'
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${IngestBucket}"
            Principal: 
              AWS: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn

  ConfigureLambdaS3Event:
    DependsOn:
      - NATRoute
      - InternetRoute
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Timeout: 60
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref LambdaSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      Layers:
        - !Ref NodeDependencies
        - !Ref Common
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          const aws = require('aws-sdk');
          const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01', signatureVersion: 'v4' });

          const { withCustomResourceResponder } = require('utility/customResource.js');
          const { decorate } = require('utility/decorator.js');

          exports.handler = decorate([
            withCustomResourceResponder({
              shortCircuitOnDeleteRequest: true
            })
          ], async (event, context) => {
            let { Bucket, Function, Event, Filters } = event.ResourceProperties;
            let params = {
              Bucket: Bucket,
              NotificationConfiguration: {
                LambdaFunctionConfigurations: [
                  {
                    LambdaFunctionArn: Function,
                    Events: [
                      Event
                    ],
                    Filter: {
                      Key: {
                        FilterRules: JSON.parse(Filters)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            };
            console.log('params:', JSON.stringify(params, null, 2));
            return await s3.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(params).promise();
          });


  ConfigureIngestClipEventOnBuild:
    DependsOn:
      - ConfigureLambdaS3Event
      - ConfigureLambdaS3EventIngestBucketAccess
      - IngestBucket
      - IngestClip
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt ConfigureLambdaS3Event.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref IngestBucket
      Function: !GetAtt IngestClip.Arn
      Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
      Filters: '[{"Name": "suffix", "Value": ".wav" }]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered the issue with my solution: I was configuring the `AWS::Lambda::Permission` improperly. Instead of granting permission to the function backing the custom resource, it should be granting permission to the actual lambda that the S3 trigger is attaching to, like so:

```yaml
  IngestClipPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref IngestClip
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      SourceArn: !GetAtt IngestBucket.Arn
```

Making this change solved the issue, and the events were created successfully.

Comment: What a coincidence I was having the exact same issue!

Comment: Glad I could help.